# Best DRY way to show the same html block in multiple django template files

Tags: django, django-templates, dry

Sorry this is a bit of a noob question.

I have a student model.

I have multiple places where the student's profile is shown. each place is a different View and template file.

Currently I'm copying and pasting the html between template views. But this means that when I make a change to the layout of the student profile I need to update it in multiple locations.

Having the exact same html code in multiple places seems to be against DRY.

What is the best way to do this in django? or are the HTML blocks considered WET stuff?

Comment: Use the [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tag to reuse the same template partial in multiple places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a reusable template in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472034/how-to-make-a-reusable-template-in-django)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add an include tag where you'll need it like so -

```
<div>
stuff
{% include 'sometemplate.html' %}
more stuff
</div>
```